# Jmeter. How to get data soap response from each tag

Tags: jmeter

I need to get name and surname from soap response from each ABC tag. Im using Xpath Extractor to get name and surname from response.

```
<XXX>
<ABC>
  <name>John</name>
  <surname>Mark</surname>
</ABC>
<ABC>
  <name>Jo</name>
  <surname>Max</surname>
</ABC>
<ABC>
  <name>Kenny</name>
  <surname>Phil</surname>
</ABC>
<ABC>
  <name>Zeo</name>
  <surname>Fergie</surname>
</ABC>
</XXX>
```

In Post-procesor BeanShell I use list to get data from response but I only get name and surname from first ABC tag (John, Mark).

```
list = new ArrayList();
list.add(vars.get("name"));
list.add(vars.get("surname"));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    sb.append(list.get(i));
    log.info("--- "+list.get(i));
}
```

Any idea how to get all names and surnames?

Comment: Check here how to get mutiple matches https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0. You should use varname_<number>

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) in order to get first and last names like:

```
//name | //surname
```

[image: XPath Extractor]

Depending on what you need to do with the results you can iterate through them using:

- [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)
- Directly access names using match number originating i.e. from [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function. See [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) article for more details on working with composite variables.

Comment: Thnx Dmitri for an answer. It returns names and surnames when I use XPath Tester but how to save them from each tag ABC, soap response returns 3 or 4 people but sometimes 15 or more. In this case my saved file shows only first name and surname but I want them all...